# How to move spit windows around in NERDTree plugin for vim?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm using the NERDTree plugin for Vim and would like to move windows around after I open them in split window view.

How do i do so?

Comment: How's that related to NERDTree, I mean moving split windows around?

Comment: when I split a window in NERDTree I'd like to the positions of two windows.

Comment: This may help: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/